# Обход IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: python, index

Пример:

```
r = [p, 2, g, "5"]
print(r[0], r[6])
```

На выводе, понятное дело, ошибка.

Есть ли возможность, чтобы вместо элемента с несуществующим индексом печать какой-либо символ, например прочерк (-)

То есть вывод должен быть:

```
p, -
```

Нужно для циклов, с разными длинами списков.
Спасибо.

## UPD

```
a1 = ["a", "b", "c"]
a2 = ["c", "a", "b"]
a3 = ["a", "b"]
a4 = ["c", "a", "f"]
r  = [a1,a2,a3,a4]

for i in range(0, len(r)): 
    u1=r[i][0] 
    u2=r[i][1] 
    u3=r[i][2] 

print(u1, u2, u3)
```

тут будет ошибка, а надо чтоб, стоял прочерк, вот так:

```
a b c c a b a b - c a f –
```

Comment: Можно конечно использовать блок try: except IndexError: Но что мешает узнать длину списка и проходить по нему с учетом длины? Или просто проходить по элементам в блоке for el in r? Ну или не использовать списки для этой задачи, так как они не очень подходят под нее. Но тогда нужен контекст, чтобы понять на что заменить.

Comment: a1=["a", "b", "c"]
a2=["c", "a", "b"]
a3=["a", "b"]
a4=["c", "a", "f"]
r=[a1,a2,a3,a4]
for i in range(0, len(r)):
    u1=r[i][0]
    u2=r[i][1]
    u3=r[i][2]
    print(u1, u2, u3)
Спасибо. Я тут новичок. Надо было сразу выложить, что надо, уточняю:
тут будет ошибка, а надо чтоб, стоял прочерк, вот так:
a b c
c a b
a b -
c a f

Answer (score 2):

Я могу предложить 2 варианта:

1. Написать функцию:

```
def print_ind(lst, index):
    try:
        print(lst[index])
    except:
        print('-')

r = ['p', 2, 'g', '5']
print_ind(r, 0)   # p
print_ind(r, 6)   # -
```

2. Создать свой класс с переопределением:

```
class MyCl(list):
    def __init__(self, lst):
        self.lst = lst

    def __getitem__(self, item):
        try:
            return self.lst[item]
        except:
            return '-'

r = MyCl(['p', 2, 'g', "5"])
print(r[0], r[6]) # p -
```

Answer (score 0):

Ну можно что-то такое изобразить.

```
import itertools

def get_dflt(seq, pos, dflt='-'):
   return itertools.islice(itertools.chain(seq, itertools.repeat(dflt)), pos, None).__next__()

print(get_dflt('ABC', 1), get_dflt('ABC', 6))
```

Comment: `return seq[pos] if pos < len(seq) else dflt` так вроде попроще?